# jQuery auto-complete form, working half the time

Tags: jquery, geocoding

I have a form with some inputs including a field for zip code. When the user inputs their zip, I'm using http://www.zippopotam.us/ zip code API to look up their city and state and put those values in a hidden field.

When I'm testing this out in the console it works great, but the city and state values are only coming through half of the time on our back-end.

Here's the code:

```
  $(function(){

  var postalField = $('#field7');
  var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/; //check for alphabet characters

  //function to call zippopotamus API
  function zippopotamus(theZip){
  var country = "";
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!theZip[0].match(alphaExp)){ //if the zip starts with a number
      //use United States api
      client.open("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/"+theZip, true);
      country = "US";
    } else { //else if it starts with a letter
      //use Canada api
      client.open("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/CA/"+theZip.substring(0,3), true);
      country = "CA";
    }

  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(client.readyState == 4) {
      var responseJSON = $.parseJSON(client.responseText);
      console.log(responseJSON);
      var city = responseJSON['places'][0]['place name'];
      $('#field8').val(city);
      var state = responseJSON['places'][0]['state abbreviation'];
      $('#field9').val(state);
      $('#field10').val(country);
      $('#field15').val(client.statusText);
    };
  };

  client.send();
  }

  postalField.on('blur submit',function(){
    var postalInput = postalField.val();

    if (postalInput !=0) { //if the postal code is not blank run the ajax
      zippopotamus(postalInput);
    }//end if statement
 } );
```

Comment: Could you create a JS Fiddle for that?

Comment: but the console always logs the correct responseJSON ?

Comment: FelipeKM here you go: http://codepen.io/mustachios/pen/IhxCp

John Smith, yes, that's correct.

Comment: post your HTML. What are these fields `#field8` type?

Comment: Nouphal.M #field8 type="hidden"

Comment: Here's a new pen including the HTML - http://codepen.io/mustachios/pen/yboGI